# Generate PDF from content in Magnolia CMS

Tags: pdf-generation, magnolia

We would like to generate a PDF document for a single page. While only [this link](http://forum.magnolia-cms.com/forum/thread.html?threadId=57b98495-1f50-4cdf-9eba-6b269f8e9168) talks about this subject (and the other discussion linked from there), the information given is quite slim.

Could anybody share any success stories made so far including source-code?

Has someone succeeded in using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)?

(we plan to use Magnolia 4.5.6)

Answer (score 0):

After evaluating both [Aspose.pdf](http://www.aspose.com/java/pdf-component.aspx) (commercial product) and [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), we went to use LaTex. We had quite some specific requirements (e.g. two column layout with footnotes, very large table), which were not possible with the two above mentioned products.

We are very happy with this solution, but there are some things to be noted: first and foremost you leave the JVM, and second LaTex is itself another macro language to be learned. The quality of the outcome is very good, although, and we are very happy with that solution.

wkhtmltopdf is used in another project, and the outcome is also good, for more straight forward formatting.